# Facebook Connect + jQuery Mobile + Phonegap Build

Tags: jquery-mobile, facebook-javascript-sdk, phonegap-build

I'm trying to understand how to use **Facebook Connect** (login) with **jQuery Mobile** and **Phonegap Build**, but as more I search about this information, more I get confused.

I have already my app created on Facebook, and I have API number.

I don't know if the best way is to call a PHP page (via ajax) where validates EMAIL + PASS via Facebook PHP SDK or Facebook SDK Javascript. For SDK JS I don't understand how to integrate it in my code (and I don't know if it's possible to test it by localhost).

If someone could help me with this question...

**Update**

I tried @Dom suggestion, but when I click in the button, any action happens.

Below my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <title>Test</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/codiqa.ext.css">

    <!-- jQuery and jQuery Mobile -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/utf8.js"></script>
    <script src="js/cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js"></script>
    <script src="js/facebook-js-sdk.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            <!-- These are the notifications that are displayed to the user through pop-ups if the above JS files does not exist in the same directory-->
            if ((typeof cordova == 'undefined') && (typeof Cordova == 'undefined')) alert('Cordova variable does not exist. Check that you have included cordova.js correctly');
            if (typeof CDV == 'undefined') alert('CDV variable does not exist. Check that you have included cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js correctly');
            if (typeof FB == 'undefined') alert('FB variable does not exist. Check that you have included the Facebook JS SDK file.');

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                               alert('auth.login event');
                               });

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
                               alert('auth.logout event');
                               });

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function(response) {
                               alert('auth.sessionChange event');
                               });

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
                               alert('auth.statusChange event');
                               });

            /*function getSession() {
                alert("session: " + JSON.stringify(FB.getSession()));
            }
            */
            function getLoginStatus() {
                FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                                  if (response.status == 'connected') {
                                  alert('logged in');
                                  } else {
                                  alert('not logged in');
                                  }
                                  });
            }
            var friendIDs = [];
            var fdata;
            function me() {
                FB.api('/me/friends', { fields: 'id, name, picture' },  function(response) {
                       if (response.error) {
                       alert(JSON.stringify(response.error));
                       } else {
                       var data = document.getElementById('data');
                       fdata=response.data;
                       console.log("fdata: "+fdata);
                       response.data.forEach(function(item) {
                                             var d = document.createElement('div');
                                             d.innerHTML = "<img src="+item.picture+"/>"+item.name;
                                             data.appendChild(d);
                                             });
                       }
                    var friends = response.data;
                    console.log(friends.length); 
                    for (var k = 0; k < friends.length && k < 200; k++) {
                        var friend = friends[k];
                        var index = 1;

                        friendIDs[k] = friend.id;
                        //friendsInfo[k] = friend;
                    }
                    console.log("friendId's: "+friendIDs);
                       });
            }

            function logout() {
                FB.logout(function(response) {
                          alert('logged out');
                          });
            }

            function login() {
                FB.login(
                         function(response) {
                            if (response.session) {
                                alert('logged in');
                            } else {
                                alert('not logged in');
                            }
                        },
                         { scope: "email" }
                         );
            }


            function facebookWallPost() {
                console.log('Debug 1');
                var params = {
                    method: 'feed',
                    name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
                    link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
                    picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
                    caption: 'Reference Documentation',
                    description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
                  };
                console.log(params);
                FB.ui(params, function(obj) { console.log(obj);});
            }

            function publishStoryFriend() {
                randNum = Math.floor ( Math.random() * friendIDs.length ); 

                var friendID = friendIDs[randNum];
                if (friendID == undefined){
                    alert('please click the me button to get a list of friends first');
                }else{
                    console.log("friend id: " + friendID );
                    console.log('Opening a dialog for friendID: ', friendID);
                    var params = {
                        method: 'feed',
                        to: friendID.toString(),
                        name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
                        link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
                        picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
                        caption: 'Reference Documentation',
                        description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
                    };
                    FB.ui(params, function(obj) { console.log(obj);});
                }
            }

            document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
                                      try {
                                      alert('Device is ready! Make sure you set your app_id below this alert.');
                                      FB.init({ appId: "appid", nativeInterface: CDV.FB, useCachedDialogs: false });
                                      document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = "";
                                      } catch (e) {
                                      alert(e);
                                      }
                                      }, false);
            </script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page_login">
    <div data-role="content" id="content-login">
        <div id="content">
            <a href="#" onclick="login()" data-role="button">Login Facebook</a>
            <a href="#" onclick="me()" data-role="button">Me</a>
            <a href="#" onclick="getLoginStatus()" data-role="button">Get Login Status</a>
            <a href="#" onclick="facebookWallPost()" data-role="button">facebookWallPost</a>
            <a href="#" onclick="publishStoryFriend()">friendstory</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "br.com.test"
        version   = "1.0.0">
    <name>Test</name>

    <!-- FB Connect Section -->
    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect">
        <param name="APP_ID" value="XXXXXXXXXX...." /> <!-- FB App ID-->
        <param name="APP_NAME" value="test" /> <!-- FB App Namespace-->
    </gap:plugin>

    <description>
        Test
    </description>

    <author href="http://test.com.br" email="atendimento@test.com.br">
        Test
    </author>

    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" />

    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />

    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.9.0" />
    <preference name="orientation"      value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device"    value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen"       value="false" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce"    value="true" />

    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:density="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />
    <icon src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png"          gap:platform="webos" />
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png"  gap:platform="winphone" />
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" gap:platform="winphone"   gap:role="background" />

    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png"         gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"    gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"     gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" gap:platform="winphone" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Take a look at the plugin documentation located [here](https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect).
2. Ensure you have the below in the `<head>` of your index.html:

   ```
   <script src="cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js"></script>
   <script src="facebook-js-sdk.js"></script>
   ```
3. Ensure your config.xml contains the below:

   ```
   <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect">
       <param name="APP_ID" value="..." />
       <param name="APP_NAME" value="..." />
   </gap:plugin>
   ```
4. Finally, review the "Simple Sample" on how to use the plugin located [here](https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect/blob/master/example/Simple/index.html)

Hope this helps. If you are still having issues, post some code you are using for us to take a look at.

Comment: I tried with your sample, but when I click in the buttons, any action happens. Check my post update. Thanks! =)

Comment: Are you testing on iOS or Android? Have you done this:

***iOS:...you will need to ensure that you have properly set up your Native iOS App settings on the Facebook App Dashboard. Please see the Getting Started with the Facebook SDK: Create a Facebook App section, for more details on this.

***Android:...you will need to generate a hash of your Android key(s) and submit those to the Developers page on Facebook to get it working. Furthermore, if you are generating this hash on Windows (specifically 64 bit versions), please use version 0.9.8e or 0.9.8d of OpenSSL for Windows and not 0.9.8k.

Comment: Ah, great! As my app is a jQuery Mobile + HTML5 + Phonegap Build, what I have to put in Package Name and Class Name?

Comment: I put for Package Name "br.com.appname" and for Class Name "br.com.appname.MainActivity". I put also the Key Hashes I generated in my computer. Facebook Login and Deep Linking options are enabled. But when I ran it on my Android device (2.3 version), and click on "Facebook Login" button, nothing happens. Is there a way to test it in localhost? Tks! =)

Comment: I ran my app in emulate.phonegap.com, and in the console I'm getting the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: login is not defined 127.0.0.1:8080/appTest/:1

Comment: Remove the "js/" from <script src="js/cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js"> and <script src="js/facebook-js-sdk.js">. You should not be including those actual .js files in your project. Phonegap Build will include them for you in the proper location. See the tag in my answer. There is no "js/". I still think it weird though that it would say "login is not defined".

Comment: That's correct. I removed JS files from my project and removed "JS/" from script tags for Facebook Connect Plugin. But, running it locally, by Ripple for Google Chrome extension, I get some erros in the console.
So I submited the app to PhoneGap Build and ran in my Android device --> the button "Login" still do anythinhg.

Comment: put an alert() at the top of your onclick function. That will at least tell us if it is even getting to the onclick event. Also, Ripple will not work for testing because your plugins and phonegap.js are not in the project yet.

Comment: Seems like interface has changed and github has changed., since this answer. https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin and the code for usage and JS files in include have changed. code example: https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/a94872583b0c6045c56d3ccb9aa2171db305db6a/platforms/android/assets/www/index.html