# Facebook Authentication using jqueryMobile and Phone Gap

Tags: jquery, facebook, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have to create a facebook authentication page using jquery mobile and Phone gap for Android and iOS.

I am pretty confused which API should i use and how to start.

Anyone please help me sort out my dillemma

Comment: Have a look at this..
[Facebook+JQM+PhoneGap][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720201/facebook-connect-jquery-mobile-phonegap-build

Comment: Yes I did refer this. As said in it the more we look for solution in google, the more we are getting confused. I am a front end developer and am confused what to do with classes suggested in that post.

Comment: Do not post duplicate questions. If you don't understand solutions in previous questions you should address that problem, don't open that question again.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but this might be of some help for you:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect">
    <param name="APP_ID" value="..." />
    <param name="APP_NAME" value="..." />
</gap:plugin>
```

References:

- https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin
- https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/257
- http://bobnisco.com/blog/view/use-facebook-login-phonegap-3x-apps